# Like and comment a Post on a Page with Open Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-comments

to evaluate the title of the question, I have created a page. And also app for getting a appID.

i have posted a like(action) on a techcrunch article(Object) on my timeline with the mention of my FB app name. **But, is it possible to let users of my website  like & comment a particular post , which the admin posted to public on my Page using graph api.**

how can we get access tokens for users to do so ?

would we still need app ID. even if it is about the facebook page. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create `Like` and `Comment` over a particular [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). And to do so you would be required to have a Facebook app and get User's authorization for `publish_stream` permission. After that you can create `Like` for a particular Post by making a HTTP POST request to

```
POST_ID/comments
```

with `message` field and would return `comment_id` as success. And like by making HTTP POST to

```
POST_ID/likes
```

which would return `true` as success on creation of like.

Comment: does the above process work ....for a post on a facebook page..i reckon this process can be done on a post of a user.

Comment: Yes it can, the Post object is after all a Post object no matter what. Just make sure to have `publissh_stream` permission.

Comment: @visista.. Are you having any other problem. If the answers solves your query then do accept it as answer so that other new questions with similar issue could solve their issues.

Comment: anvesh, would i need access tokens for users?

Comment: @visista, yes you would be required User Access token with `publish_stream` permission.

Comment: [Debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token) your access token to check if that is still valid for the user or not.

Comment: it is still valid. And to make the scenario clear i will explain what i am trying to do . i have created a page and app in facebook. using appid for login. i want to make a comment  from the logged in user on a post by using FB.api('/post_id/comments','message:,access_token:') but i am unable to retrieve access token. i am using FB.authReponse method, but no luck.

Comment: I think you are using JS-SDK, and if that's the case then you actually, don't require to explicitly provide for the access token, as soon as the User logs in you app, JS-SDK will utilize cookie to take care of User Management.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails, you can use gems like 'Koala' to easily use Open Graph API.
After you initialize open graph object and have object ID of the post, you can use gem methods to comment or like:

```
token = user.access_token
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
post_id = @graph.put_wall_post("hey, i'm testing!")
@graph.put_comment(post_id, "Comment")
@graph.put_like(post_id)
```